# when i enabled receiver to be instantiated by the system its showing app not responding

Tags: android

when i enabled receiver to be instantiated by the system to show notification info from its onclick, apps showing dialog apps not responding .

logcat:

```
D/ANRAppManager: !!! It is not under singleton mode, U can't use it. !!!
03-18 17:13:18.593 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
                                                                                          at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
                                                                                          at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
                                                                                          at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
                                                                                          at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                                                                                          at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:682)
                                                                                          at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.mediatek.anrappmanager.IFrameworks.serviceManagerGetService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.b(SourceFile:77)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$1.c(SourceFile:75)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative$a.get(SourceFile:97)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRManagerNative.getDefault(SourceFile:35)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at com.mediatek.anrappmanager.ANRAppManager.dumpMessageHistory(SourceFile:59)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpMessageHistory(ActivityThread.java:1244)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:682)
    03-18 17:13:18.594 24690-24726/com.systechdigital.dashboardnotification W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:451)
```

manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".ServiceClass"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name=".NotificationActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadCastReceiverClass"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="Notification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

receiverClass:

```
if(result!=null) {
            intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("NotificationList", result);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

here sending notification from asynctask inside service:

```
if (result != null) {


                //notification

                NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.systech_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Delivered")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                ;

                intent1 = new Intent(context, BroadCastReceiverClass.class);
                intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent1.setAction("Notification");
                context.sendBroadcast(intent1);

                Intent notificationActivityIntent=new Intent(context,NotificationActivity.class);
                notificationActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(notificationActivityIntent);

                intent1.putExtra("Result",result);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent1);


                TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
                taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);

//                PendingIntent pendingIntent=taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0,notification.build());
            }
```

can you please find me out where is my mistake.